# Inheritance in c++, output inside

Tags: c++, inheritance, output

i have this code:
the details comes after..

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class A {
public:
    A() { cout << "A::A()" << endl; }
    A(const A& a) :i(a.i) { cout << "A::A(A&)" << endl; }
private:
    T i;
};
template <class T>
class B {
public:
    B(A<T> aa) : a(aa) { cout << "B::B(A)" << endl; }
    B(const B& b) : a(b.a) { cout << "B::B(B&)" << endl; }
    A<T> a;
};
class C : public B<int> {
public:
    C(A<int> aa) : B<int>(aa), a(aa){ cout << "C::C(A aa)" << endl; }
    ~C() { cout << "C::~C()" << endl; }
    A<int> a;
};
void main()
{
    cout << "--1--" << endl;
    A<int> a;
    cout << "--2--" << endl;
    C c(a);
}
```

and the output is:

```
--1--
A::A()
--2--
A::A(A&)
A::A(A&)
A::A(A&)
B::B(A)
A::A(A&)
C::C(A aa)
C::~C()
Press any key to continue . . .
```

my question is why copy constructor of class A called 3 times before constructor of class B ??

thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C(A aa) : B(aa), a(aa)
calls

```
1.B<int>(aa) -- calls B(A<T> aa), call by value, so A::A(const A& a) is called
2. a(aa) -- calls A::A(const A& a)
3. C(A<int> aa) (aa passed by value, so, A::A(const A& a) is called
```

Thst's why you have copy constructor of class A called 3 times

Answer (score 2):

It's quite clear if you follow the chain of constructor calls:

- Once to pass a copy of `a` by value to the constructor of `C`.
- Once to pass a copy of that by value to the constructor of `B`.
- Once to copy-construct the member `a` of `B`.

You can avoid the first two by changing those constructors to take their argument by reference, as the copy-constructor of `A` does.

Answer (score 2):

First you pass to `C(A<int> aa)` which is a copy
This goes to `B(A<T> aa)` which is a copy
Then it's copied again here `a(aa)`

Pass by const reference to avoid these copies.

Just so you are aware, these classes do not need an explicitly defined copy constructor.